# IOS5 Getting better performance in a moving text display

Tags: drawtext

I am creating a moving text display with a huge font size.
The faster the text moves, the less smooth the text transition becomes.
I am calling NSString drawAtPoint evere 0.01 second (NSTimer) and move the text 1 point.

Would there be a better option for the drawing? Maybe using a UILabel or UIScrollView?

Any advise is welcome!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the animation features of the system?

eg: [[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Comment: Thanks Alex, that indeed looks more suitable.

Comment: Used the animation. Still a little blur on the letters edges when the text is moving in huge fontsize. But I am using the simulator.....  The movement itself is more smooth though.